# Limiting documents in temporary views

Tags: couchdb

I'm playing around with the map and reduce through temporary views, but at 1,000,000+ documents it is a bit slow, rather than creating a separate dataset for testing, is it possible to only use a subset of data in the temporary view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map-reduce view is more like "CREATE INDEX" than it is like "SELECT * FROM".

In other words, when you do a map-reduce view, CouchDB will crunch through every document.

However, for testing, one thing you can do is make a normal view (not temporary). Just develop your work in a temporary design document, `_design/my_experiments`.

Save your map-reduce view code and then query the view with the `?stale=update_after` option. You will probably get no results, however `stale=update_after` will tell CouchDB to begin processing the view. Now try your query again. You will see the results that have been processed so far. Now try a third time. You will see even more data reflected.

Roughly speaking, views process documents in the same order that a `_changes` query returns them to you: basically the first update is processed first, and then in order and the most recent change is processed last.

Comment: seems a little complicated, maybe just because it is still so new to me, but I'm thinking I might as well just create a data subset for testing, and apply the view to the full data once I'm happy with the results in the testing view